# How to navigate based on a condition in RNRF react native

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I would like to navigate to new screen only if login is successful, I tried using {Actions.HomeScreen} inside if condition but it does not do anything.

here is the code:

```
async login() {
const res = await api.getLoginResult();
const status= res.status;
console.log('log'+status);
if(status==='success'){
  {Actions.HomeScreen;}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've forgotten to actually invoke the function, it should be:

```
async login() {
  const res = await api.getLoginResult();
  const status = res.status;
  console.log('log' + status);
  if(status === 'success') {
    Actions.HomeScreen(); // Note the parens ()
  }
}
```